# Visual studio intellisense does not see new methods until restart?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I have a fairly large C# project with many files, classes etc. Everything works fine but if I move to say ClassA and add a new method or property and then move to another file in the solution and attempt to access it the intellisense reports it does not exist and underlines it in red. If I build the solution it will correctly build without errors and the red lines will disappear until I start editing the file again and then the red lines will come back and be reported as errors.

Saving the solution and all files does not help, but if I restart visual studio it will then work as intended unless I add more new methods/properties to an existing class then I have to restart again or suffer same problem.

I had this problem a long time ago with visual studio express and I could never fix it but it went away when I upgraded to a newer visual studio.  Now the problem has come back with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on windows 8.1 and I can't find any solution again :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that your intellisense options are still properly configured.

Go to Tools => Options => Text Editor => C# => Intellisense.

Make sure that under "Completion Lists"

(checked) Show completion list after a character is typed

Make sure that under "Selection in completion list" you have:

Committed by typing the following characters: `{}[]().,:;+-*/%&|^!~=<>?@#'"\`

and

(checked) Committed by pressing the space bar

Comment: I went to the screen you mentioned and everything was already set how you suggested to set it.  However after pressing OK on the options menu simply having opened it seems to of fixed the intellisense issue!  It has however left another strange issue - the error list at bottom of the project reports 99 errors and if I fix one it does NOT remove from the list.. unless I restart the IDE!

Comment: When I have a large list of errors like that the menu doesn't always update properly until I fix all of them. I'm not sure if that's your issue, but I often have to fix them all before the project will refresh the error list.