# SendGrid 'DeliverAsync()' Not Working

Tags: api, azure, sendgrid

I'm trying to send an email with Azure and SendGrid. I have it all set up (I think) and my code is as per below, but the 'DeliverAsync()' method is not working and there is no 'Deliver()' option available.

Here are my using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using SendGrid;
```

Here is my code: 'transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage)' is showing as plain black text.

```
// Create the email object first, then add the properties.

        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo("d@gmail.com");
        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("d@gmail.com", "John Smith");
        myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library";
        myMessage.Text = "Hello World!";

        var apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

// create a Web transport, using API Key

        var transportWeb = new Web(apiKey);

// Send the email, which returns an awaitable task.

        transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
```

I'm hoping someone has seen this before and knows the solution. There are a lot of similar problems online, but none I've found with a fix to this. I am using SendGrid v6.3.4. I have tried reverting to v6.3.3 but it didnt help. My stats in SendGrid show zero for everything, no emails sent, no requests, no bounces etc.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried creating a new Email class to remove any clutter and make this clearer, the 'DeliverAsync' method is still not being recognized after transportWeb.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using SendGrid;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CPWebsite
{
    public class Email
    {
        static async void Main()
        {
            try
            {

                // Create the email object first, then add the properties.
                var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
                myMessage.AddTo("d@gmail.com");
                myMessage.From = new MailAddress("d@gmail.com", "John Smith");
                myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library";
                myMessage.Text = "Hello World!";

                var apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                // create a Web transport, using API Key
                var transportWeb = new Web(apiKey);

                // Send the email, which returns an awaitable task.
                await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing `var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();` to `SendGridMessage myMessage = new SendGridMessage();` but no luck. Only the following using statements are showing as necessary.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using SendGrid;
```

Im trying anything at this point!

Comment: I don't know SendGrid but I would first try to call the synchronous method first to see if credentials and everything are in place. Synchronous first because that will give you a return value that will have statuscode and message to tell you what is going on.

Comment: This is just a heads up and in reply to Allen's comment above about synchronous methods, the SendGrid C# Library no longer has a synchronous Deliver() method.

Comment: I might be missing a using statement for the Async method...?

Comment: Ok, I have the await working by adding the 'async' to my method e.g: 'protected async void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)' but the 'DeliverAsync' is still showing as black text and not being recognised...

Comment: I have updated my original post if anyone has any more ideas?

Comment: Still cant figure this out so I've decided to move on and enable email capabilities at the end when I've done everything else. I'll post back here when I manage to solve it in the future. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a console app currently? You'll need to await the method otherwise the console apps main thread will complete execution and cause the worker threads to be killed before they successfully deliver the message.

Try:

```
await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
```

Also add the following to your using statements:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Comment: Hi, its an Asp.Net website application. I tried await eg: await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage); but I get an error that 'The await operator can only be used within an Async method'.

Comment: Ok, I have the await working by adding the 'async' to my method e.g: 'protected async void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)' but the 'DeliverAsync' is still showing as black text and not being recognised...

Comment: What do you mean by "is still showing as black text and not being recognised"?

Comment: I am using the Tools>Options>General>Blue color theme in VS2015. General code such as variables are in Black font, Classes are in Light Blue colored font. --- My statement should show as: await [Dark Blue Font] transportWeb[Black Font].DeliverAsync[Light Blue Font](myMessage)[Black Font]; --- Because 'DeliverAsync' is black it is not being recognised as a class I think. --- When I type 'transportWeb.', the quick context menu shows DeliverAsync as "awaitable System.Threading.Tasks.Task Web.DeliverAsync(ISendGrid message) Usage: await DeliverAsync(...);"

Comment: When I type 'transportWeb.', the other options are all objects: Equals, GetHashCode, GetType or ToString.

Comment: DeliverAsync is not a class. It is a method. Please see what I added to my answer pertaining to adding the using System.Threading.Tasks;

Comment: I added 'using System.Threading.Tasks;' and 'await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);' The DeliverAsync method is still not recognised and the System.Threading.Tasks is showing as unnecessary...

Comment: I have updated my original post if anyone has any more ideas?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using (2013, 2015, etc?)

Comment: Does the project build even though intellisense says there's a problem? Perhaps you're also experiencing something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830813/visual-studio-intellisense-does-not-see-new-methods-until-restart

Comment: Still cant figure this out so I've decided to move on and enable email capabilities at the end when I've done everything else. I'll post back here when I manage to solve it in the future. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

My project (Windows Service) was essentially synchronous with respect to specific thread where SendGrid was called, and hence what I had to do to make it work is to add **.Wait()** after the *.DeliverAsync()*.

And so, try:

```
static void Main()
```

and later:

```
transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage).Wait();
```

There is actually a little foot-note in SendGrid documentation eluding to this technique.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this has been resolved but try using myMessage.Html for the body instead of myMessage.Text. Especially if you are using html in the body. I have pretty much the same setup and my code works fine.